# ZF2, Using WHERE in Db\SQL

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to build a SQL object using ZF2's Db\SQL.

Below is my code.

```
    $sql = new Sql($this->database);
    $predicate = new Where();
    $query = $sql->select();
    $query->from('sessions');
    $query->columns(array('sessiondata'));
    $query->where($predicate->equalTo('sessionid', $sessionId));
    $query->where($predicate->greaterThan('expire', new Expression("NOW()")));
```

As you can read, I'm doing a session read.

The preparing is failing on the execute because of the [last] where property:

```
$query->where($predicate->greaterThan('expire', 'NOW()'));
```

Unfortunately, ZF2 doesn't tell me why it's failed, all I know is that `Statement could not be executed`

What am I doing wrong in the above?

I think that prepare is interpreting the thing as literally as it can, hence the presence of the mysql function `Now()` is causing it to fail. How do I get past this?

EDIT: Actually, it's the execution that's failing.

Comment: in the exception you have, check if there is parent exception with actual error message

Comment: Actually, ZF just throws an exception, no data is captured.

Comment: Zend\Db throws exception with useless message, but it is setting exception from PDO/MySQLi as previous: http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getprevious.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try debug the final query. You can use mysql query logger for that.
In my.cnf(or my.ini) you set:

log = "C:/genquery.log"

OR

log = "/var/log/mysql/error.log"

depending on system.

Then reset mysql server and you can analyze what really happened.